# XML Parser for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

Is there any XMLParser other than NSXMLParser to parse the XML data. I mean some opensource library that parses XML string and returns us a Dictionary or Array or some Data Structure.
In an application i need XMLParser frequently so that i want a class for that.

Comment: I swear this gets asked once a week. Search. Bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these out:

[How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

[How To Read and Write XML Documents with GDataXML](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

Answer (score 0):

See also:

Cocoa Literature List: XML

http://osx.hyperjeff.net/Reference/CocoaArticles?cat=50